# How to find Kubernetes naming restrictions?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any doc and go file that shows all the various naming restrictions for Kubernetes entities? I am interested in charset and length restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [identifiers doc on Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/docs/design/identifiers.md) is the closest thing to what you're looking for.